# Qt - Change the color of a QSvgWidget

Tags: python, qt, svg, pyqt

I have an SVG image that I add to my Qt Layout

```py
mySvg = QtSvg.QSvgWidget('/path/to/hello.svg')
layout.addWidget(mySvg)
```

The color of the rendered SVG is black. How can I change this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is a more elegant solution but I implemented this by editing directly the `xml/svg` content via the python standard module `xml.etree.ElementTree`.
I do not know the `svg` specification, but in my case the *path* I want to change the color has the tag `path`. Possibly the tag must be changed for other files.
With the second method you can get the `svg` as a `QByteArray` which you can directly handover into the `QSvgWidget`.

In my case some other modifications on the `svg` content were necessary - with this approach you are very flexible.
Maybe it makes (more) sense to subclass the `QSvgWidget` to integrate this functionality.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Et

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QByteArray
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor


class Icon:

    def __init__(self, icon_path, color=Qt.white):

        self.tree = Et.parse(icon_path)
        self.root = self.tree.getroot()

        self._change_path_color(color)

    def _change_path_color(self, color):
        c = QColor(color)
        paths = self.root.findall('.//{*}path')
        for path in paths:
            path.set('fill', c.name())

    def get_QByteArray(self):
        xmlstr = Et.tostring(self.root, encoding='utf8', method='xml')
        return QByteArray(xmlstr)
```

EDIT: The *-wildcard in the xpath (`.//{*}path`) is a new feature within python 3.8. For prev. versions the namespace must be specified in the xpath:

```
self.namespace = root.tag.split('}')[0].strip('{')
...
paths = self.root.findall(f'.//{{{self.namespace}}}path')
```